# Uniform vs legacy initialisation producing different compilation results

Tags: c++, c++17, uniform-initialization

I alighted on this while permuting with a trivial piece of code:

```
struct Base0 {};
struct Base1 {};

template<typename... Ts>
struct Derived: Ts... {};

int main() {
    Derived<Base0, Base1> d0 {Base0{}, Base1{}}; // OK
    Derived<Base0, Base1> d1 (Base0{}, Base1{}); // ERROR
}
```

I thought both `d0` and `d1` should have resulted in a compilation error since I can't see how `Derived` without any matching ctor takes ctor arguments as passed and flags `d0`'s compilation as fine.

There's probably something obvious I'm missing. What is it about the uniform initialisation that's making it pass ? Is it aggregate initialisation or something ? What's happening with the temporaries passed to the ctor ?

[Using C++17 online compiler here](https://onlinegdb.com/HJZYTzvGS)

**Edit**

As asked, I'm providing a copy-paste of the spew-out:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:9:47: error: no matching function for call to ‘Derived::Derived(Base0, Base1)’
     Derived<Base0, Base1> d1 (Base0{}, Base1{}); // ERROR
                                               ^
main.cpp:5:8: note: candidate: constexpr Derived::Derived()
 struct Derived: Ts... {};
        ^~~~~~~
main.cpp:5:8: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
main.cpp:5:8: note: candidate: constexpr Derived::Derived(const Derived&)
main.cpp:5:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
main.cpp:5:8: note: candidate: constexpr Derived::Derived(Derived&&)
main.cpp:5:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
```

Comment: What are the actual errors you get from the example you show? Please copy-paste (as text) the full and complete output into the question, as it might have some notes that could give hints about the problem.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude pasted the error now. Seems I got an insta-downvote, so I'm assuming it is indeed something obvious i'm missing :D

Comment: @ustulation Instadownvote for no [mcve] or error in the question is fairly usual. Most of us don't have time to keep asking for details _in the question_ on _every single question_ (which is seemingly what would otherwise be required!)

Comment: Ah fair enough, been a long time since i posted. Good reminder !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196999/discussion-between-aconcagua-and-lightness-races-in-orbit).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit OK finally the discussion opened, so I consequently deleted my comments here, suppose we'd just be spoiling the question otherwise...

Comment: @Aconcagua Cool me too

Comment: Note that C++20 **does** allow the syntax with parentheses, partly because it is that syntax that is used by forwarding functions like `make_unique` or `emplace`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like this is a new C++17 feature of [aggregate initialisation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization):

> **Each direct public base, (since C++17)** array element, or non-static class member, in order of array subscript/appearance in the class definition, **is copy-initialized from the corresponding clause of the initializer list.**

It comes with the change that a class with bases may now be an aggregate (as long as they are not `virtual`, `private`, or `protected`… though they don't even need to be aggregates! ).

Your failing case does not use aggregate initialisation, but instead attempts a good old-fashioned constructor invocation. As you've identified, no such constructor exists.

Comment: Fun fact, the base need not be an aggregate itself to be usable.

Comment: This whole thing is news to me btw. Nais

Comment: @NathanOliver Basically just like data members of the aggregate :)

Comment: @Rakete1111 Yeah it's mad innit

Comment: about "is copy-initialized from the..." in your answer, does it work even if the copy-ctor is deleted for the base ? I just tried deleting default ctor and copy operations for `Base0` and it still works. I can edit the question to put in this detail if it's relevant.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Ah in which case i'm totally convinced and don't need any further info :D. But na, on a more serious note, why so (probably should have asked that instead) and what's happening to the passed temporaries `Base0{}` and `Base1{}`.

Comment: @ustulation There are no temporaries.  C++17 also has guaranteed copy elision so the bases are directly constructed from the initializers.

Comment: Cheers, but as I also mentioned in the comment that I deleted all ctors explicitly. How is anything for that type allowed to be constructed then ? [For ref](https://onlinegdb.com/HkczrQDMS)

Comment: @ustulation Because no copy happened.  C++17 guarantees that it uses the initializer for the "temporary" to instead directly initialize the source.  You don't need an accessible copy/move constructor for this to work.  This now allows us to build factory functions for any type, even if they cant be moved and can't be copied.

Comment: Ah right ! Quite a bit to grok for me here then. Cheers all !

Comment: @NathanOliver So elision is "behind" copy-initialisation? Interesting. I went looking briefly but realised I couldn't be arsed. Odd naming though at least!

Comment: @ustulation Yeah I was just joking really ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeah.  The compiler sees it needs to make a copy, but it is making a copy from a prvalue, so instead of making a copy, it elides the operation and directly initializes the source the with prvalue's initializer.

Comment: The thing that also threw me off was that a deleted default ctor (and no other parameterised ctors) together with deleted all other likely generated ctors, in my mind meant the object was in-constructible. The only way I could get it to fail is by setting the dtor as deleted. But that's due to a different reason (and I can always create it on the heap).

Comment: @NathanOliver The fact that it's still called "copy-initialisation" threw me off. I thought perhaps that would be something that occurs when elision doesn't, rather than being something that potentially triggers elision. Just a matter of how the wording's structured innit